# Incorrect syntax near '(' and near '='

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

What I'm trying to do is to update an entry, and if it doesn't exist - create a new one.

[This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/miah/2008/02/17/sql-if-exists-update-else-insert/) is what I'm trying to follow.

I'm getting a syntax error exception, and I have no idea what's wrong.

---

That's how I make my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rides] (
    [phone]       VARCHAR (32)  NOT NULL,
    [destination] VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [departure]   VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [time]        DATETIME      NOT NULL,
    [comment]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([phone] ASC)
);
```

That's my query:

```
SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText =
@"UPDATE Rides SET (destination=@Dest, departure=@Depart, time=@Time, comment=@Comment) WHERE phone=@UName
IF (@@ROWCOUNT=0)
    INSERT INTO Rides VALUES (destination=@Dest, departure=@Depart, time=@Time, comment=@Comment)";

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UName", entry.phone);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dest", entry.destinationID);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Depart", entry.departureID);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", entry.time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff"));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment", entry.comment);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

That's `entry`:

```
public struct Entry
{
    public string phone;
    public string destinationID;
    public string departureID;
    public DateTime time;
    public string comment;
}
```

That's my error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '('.
>
> Incorrect syntax near '='.

Stack trace:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '('.
Incorrect syntax near '='.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +2442126
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5736904
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +628
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +3731
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +225
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) +2026
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +375
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +337
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +280
   RidesDatabaseAccessor.updateEntry(Entry entry) in c:\Users\Climax708\Documents\Programming\TrempLehayal\App_Code\RidesDatabaseAccessor.cs:145
   newride.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Climax708\Documents\Programming\TrempLehayal\newride.aspx.cs:75
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2952
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made the following changes:

1. I added a semicolon between your two statements (the `UPDATE` and
   the `INSERT`).
2. I removed the parentheses from your `UPDATE` statement (they aren't
   needed)
3. I corrected the syntax of your `INSERT` statement. The column names
   have to be given separately in their own parenthetical statement
   before `VALUES`.

   ```
   command.CommandText = @"UPDATE Rides 
        SET destination=@Dest, departure=@Depart, time=@Time, comment=@Comment 
        WHERE phone=@UName; 
        IF (@@ROWCOUNT=0)
            INSERT INTO Rides (destination, departure, time, comment) 
            VALUES (@Dest, @Depart, @Time, @Comment)";
   ```

Comment: While you have correctly spotted the problem, I think you should tell the OP what you have changed otherwise he will risk to loose hours to find the difference.

Comment: Thanks! I added an explanation.

Comment: Just a little fix. In case of insert, he needs to insert also the telephone number

Answer (score 0):

In your update you must not use the ( ) around the column for set

```
UPDATE Rides 
SET destination = @Dest, 
    departure = @Depart, 
    time = @Time, 
    comment = @Comment 
WHERE phone = @UName
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try

@"UPDATE Rides SET destination=@Dest, departure=@Depart, time=@Time, comment=@Comment WHERE phone=@UName

insted of your update query

Comment: That doesn't solve the OP's problem. They want to insert a new row if one doesn't exist.